# CEdit and GetwindowText in MFC

Tags: c++, visual-studio, mfc

I have added a simple Cedit control to my dialog and have an `OnEnChangeEdit` callback. I am trying to retrieve the text that is typed in the box, but can only get the first character of what is typed in that call to printf below:

```
void MFCDlg::OnEnChangeEdit() { 
  CString s; 
  m_platformSliceOverrideEditBox.GetWindowText(s); 
  _cprintf("%s", s.GetString());
}
```

If it helps I am using the Unicode character set for compilation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`_cprintf` expects ansi strings. If you are using unicode then it will stop at the first character because the second byte will be a null.

use `_tcprintf` instead which will expect wide strings when you build as unicode.

Comment: Thanks this has worked! But how come I have been able to use _cprintf all along when I was compiling using uni-code? The behaviour of _cprintf when printing std::string and char* was all fine.

Comment: std::string is single byte. You want std::wstring for unicode.